# Shell, redirect all output to a file but still print echo

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant

I have multiple vagrant provisions (shell scripts), and I would like to redirect all command output to a file while keeping the `echo` output in stdout.

Currently I redirect all output by doing

```
exec &>> provision.log
```

At the beginning of each provision

Which works great, but console is empty. So I would like to redirect everything **but** the echo commands to a file.

If there would be a possibility of redirecting all output (including echo) to a file and keeping only echo in stdout that would be the best.

Result should look like:

**Console**

```
Starting provision "master"
Updating packages...
Installing MySQL...
ERROR! check provision.log for details
```

**provision.log**

```
Starting provision "master"
Updating packages...
...
(output from apt-get)
...
Installing MySQL...
...
(output from apt-get install mysql-server-5.5)
...
ERROR! check provision.log for details
```

I do realize I could attach output redirect to every command but that is quite messy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take this approach of duplicating stdout file descriptor and using a custom `echo` function redirecting to duplicate file descriptor.

```
#!/bin/bash

# open fd=3 redirecting to 1 (stdout)
exec 3>&1

# function echo to show echo output on terminal
echo() {
   # call actual echo command and redirect output to fd=3 and log file
   command echo "$@"
   command echo "$@" >&3
}

# redirect stdout to a log file    
exec >>logfile

printf "%s\n" "going to file"
date
echo "on stdout"
pwd

# close fd=3
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: This is great, almost there. What could I add to the override echo function to log to the file as well as to console?

Comment: Magic ! the echo output is a little broken now though. som lines are appearing before/after the others

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. Now I just have to figure out how to set this globally on vagrant so I dont have to include it in every provision file. While I have your attention, When I do `echo "Nginx version $(nginx -v)` It prints first line the result of `nginx -v` and second line `Nginx version`. Any way to get them on same line?

Comment: It seems to be doing only with some packages, some package versions are being printed on same line

Comment: It could be because of `nginx` writing it on stderr. What does `nginx -V | cat -vte` show to you?

Comment: Loads of stuff. First line is version, next "built with" next "TLS SNI support enabled" and next "config arguments" very long string

Comment: Hmm in that case use it like this: `{ printf "%s" "Nginx version"; nginx -v; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136748/discussion-between-tom-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

You might redirect only *stdout* and keep *stderr* on the terminal. Of course your script should then `echo` to *stderr*, perhaps using `echo something > /dev/stderr` or `echo something >&2`

You could also redirect echo-s to `/dev/tty` which makes sense only if the script was started on a terminal (not e.g. thru `at` or `crontab`)